# Change of measure Radon-Nikodym

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes, random-variables, radon-nikodym

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ be a measure space where $P$ is a probability measure.
Let $Q$ be another probability measure that is absolutely continuous with respect to $P$.
By Radon-Nikodym, there is $L \in \mathcal{L}^1(P)$ subject to
$$
Q(A) = \int_A L(\omega) P(\mathrm{d} \omega)
$$
Does it generally hold that $\mathbb{E} \left[L X\right] = \mathbb{E}_Q \left[ X \right]$ for integrable r.v. $X$?
I see this result again and again with densities $X = f \cdot m$, but I want to know whether or not this holds without the assumption of having densities.

EDIT: $X, L$ are in $\mathcal{L}^2$.

Comment: Unless L is bounded or both L and X are L^2 (so Cauchy Schwartz applies) I think the general result you are looking for might not hold as the product of two L^1 random variables need not be L^1, there might be counterexamples, even in the density framework.

Comment: I get what you're saying. I have added such that boundedness can be achieved by Cauchy Schwartz. But RN does not guarantee that $L$ in $\mathcal{L}^2$, so it is a smaller class of probability measures $Q$ that fulfills this.

Comment: Then $ \mathbb{E}_Q \left[ X \right]=\mathbb{E} \left[L X\right] \leq \mathbb{E} \left[L^2 \right]^{1/2}.\mathbb{E} \left[ X^2\right]^{1/2}<\infty$ by Cauchy-Schwartz inequality so the result holds in this case.

Comment: $X$ is $Q$-integrable if and only if $LX$ is $P$-integrable, and in that case $\Bbb E_Q[X] =\Bbb E_P[LX]$.

Comment: Sure John but this is tautological claim IMO.

Comment: @TheBridge: It's not tautological in the least. Rather it clarifies an ambiguity ("integrable r.v. $X$") in the statement of the problem.

Comment: Well if you think this was ambiguous then you might have point, the way I see it is more like translating the word "cat" in another language, this doesn't provide any insight to what a "cat" is.

Comment: Literally "ambiguous" (="capable of being understood in two or more possible senses"), in that there is "integrable with respect to $P$" and  "integrable with respect to $Q$". In your metaphor, which part of the question is playing the role of "cat"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a little bit of ambiguity when you say "$X$ is an integrable random variable."
Assuming you mean "$X$ is a $Q$-integrable random variable," yes, this is true.  I don't know for sure whether it is true if we only have $X$ is $P$-integrable.  To show it is true when $X$ is $Q$-integrable, use the standard method of showing it is true when $X$ is a simple random variable, then show it for general $X$ by approximating with an increasing sequence of simple functions and applying the monotone convergence theorem.

Comment: Ok, thanks, works out fine!